# Fetch image from Url and keep its original size

Tags: android

I fetch image from URL with this code block:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//from web
try {
    Log.i(TAG,""+g.getPath());
    InputStream is = new URL(g.getPath()).openStream();
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, bmOptions);
    is.close();
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = 2;
    o2.inMutable = true;
    is = new URL(g.getPath()).openStream();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, o2);
    is.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Download is successful but the image's size is not the orginal size. It is lower resolution. How can I get the image in its orginal size from Url?

Comment: give us an example url from the urls you are fetching. It could be that the picture is thumbnail and you should add _n at the end, but give an example

Comment: try using this awesome library http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Why you calling `new URL(g.getPath()).openStream()` two times in same method.

Comment: @GabriellaAngelova i check url . image it is not thumbnail

Comment: @KaranMer i know picasso but it is work only show image in imageview. I dont know how can i get bitmap with picasso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line

```
    o2.inSampleSize = 2;
```

You can also use 
                  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, bmOptions );

No need to create new BitmapOptions

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing twice what you should do once. Use:

```
//from web
try {
    InputStream is = new URL(g.getPath()).openStream(); //open the stream
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null); //decode it without options
    is.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that, depending on the picture, loading it in full resolution might easily break your code and throw an `OutOfMemoryException`. In those cases you jut use the `inSampleSize` as you did; `inSampleSize = 2` means that both width and height will be half the original value.

Answer (score 0):

Code for **getting** **original size** of **image** from **URL**

Initialize variable:

```
private ImageView mImageView;
```

Bind View:

```
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
```

Async Task for get image from URL:

```
private class LoadImageInBackGround extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {

        private String imageUrl , imageName;

        public LoadImageInBackGround(String url, String file_name) {
            this.imageUrl = url;
            this.imageName = file_name;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {
                InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(this.imageUrl);
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, this.imageName);
                return d;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
        private Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
            URL url = new URL(address);
            Object content = url.getContent();
            return content;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(result);
        }
    }
```

How to **call** async task:

```
new LoadBackgroundMain("Image_Url","My_Image").execute();
```

You have to **add permissions** in **manifest** file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Done**

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code little bit

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//from web
try {
    Log.i(TAG,""+g.getPath());
    InputStream is = new URL(g.getPath()).openStream();
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = 0;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, o2);
    is.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```